# Physical interpretation of Ergodicity.

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

If $R_{\alpha}:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is defined by $$R_{\alpha}(x)=x+\alpha $$
then $R_{\alpha} $is called a *circle rotation*, and it is known that $R_{\alpha}$ is ergodic iff $\alpha$ is irrational. I interpret this to mean that the dynamical system determined by the orbit $R_\alpha^t(x)$ is ergodic, and I currently do not have a physical interpretation of this (either on $[0,1]$ or the circle) . Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity) says the dynamical system is ergodic if it "has the same behavior averaged over time as averaged over the space of the system's states." What does this mean on the circle? (My guess would be that it spends approximately the same time at each point)

Further, how would this interpretation differ in the case that our dynamical system is over a skew product of rotations of a circle: I.e., if we rotate by an irrtaional angle $\alpha$ and switch to another (identical) circle whenever our orbit lands in a predetermined subinterval of irrational length?

Comment: Your guess is correct. Ergodicity (with respect to some measure, here we take arc length) can be heuristically understood as time average=space average. What it means is that if you divide the circle into N bins of varying sizes, and start your dynamical system in one of the bins, the time spent in each of bins will be proportional to the area of that bin. In the limit of each bin size going to 0, you get the result that each point is visited the same number of times.

Comment: @nonlinearism For rotations on the circle, most points are never visited.

Comment: @Did: Indeed. I guess a better way to put it to motivate physical interpretation would be that "the neighborhood of each point is visited the same number of times".

Comment: @nonlinearism Are there any other (non-obvious) measures we can use here besides $1-\mu$, where $\mu$ is the arc lencth?